# Crontab will not run a script that i can run manualy

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm in the process of getting my AAS degree and am an intern at a local company. I have little to no experience with Linux and this is all learn as i go. my boss told me he wanted to have some scripts run automatically and suggested crontab. I done my research and am pretty sure that i have the correct formatting for the crontab commands, but i'm having problems getting at least one of the scripts to run.

i open Crontab via sudo crontab -e and have these commands

```
*/30 * * * * root /home/administrator/Desktop/rsyncbackup
0 23 * * * root /home/administrator/Desktop/snapshot
```

the rsync script will run no problem. it even outputs to a log file. everything is showing on time.

the snapshot script is refusing to run though. I have looked around and changed it from a relative path(./script) to a specific path. I have changed from * 23 run time to 0 23 run time. I am getting a little confused. and i have been changing the times to try and get it to run, with no success.

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is a snapshot script, without needing a pw

cd /media/administrator/Media/Snapshot

mkdir /media/administrator/Media/Snapshot/$(date +%F)

cp -a -l /media/administrator/Media/Data /media/administrator/Media/Snapshot/$(date +%F)/

echo "Snapshot complete: $(date) >> /home/administrator/Desktop/snaplog.log
```

Comment: I would first try running `sudo /home/administrator/Desktop/snapshot` and see if there are any errors there, since this will be run as root. Secondly, I'm not sure what `root` does there in those lines, so you could experiment with removing it.

Comment: from what i understand where root is, is a user column, meaning that i am telling it to run the scripts as root. it was an experimental thing. i was not sure if it mattered or not. thanks. as for running the script would there be any difference between running it as `sudo ./snapshot` and `sudo /home/administrator/Desktop/snapshot` ?

Comment: My Boss figured out the problem. Crontab is running fine, however some of the files are too big for the script to do what it needs to do, so it's messing up outside of Crontab.